# z-index on iPhone/mobile version of site

Tags: iphone, css, z-index

I've created an HTML5/reponsive-ish page and am now using media queries to create a seperate iPhone version. It's still in progress, so so many things wrong with it, but one issue is driving me slightly nuts.

My smartphone layout is much different to my desktop/iPad version, so I've had to use absolute positioning to get the iPhone assets into place. I've got a bit of title text that simply will not layer over the cassette image div no matter what I do.

This is the title css:

```
`   #playlistTitle {
        width:140px;
        height:32px;
        position:absolute;
        top:120px;
        left:60px;
        z-index:500;
        background-color:transparent;
        border:1px solid red;
        text-align:center;
`
```

and this is the div it's supposed to layer over:

```
`    #reelWrapper {
    height:137px;
    width:254px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:156px 6px 6px 16px;
    background:url(../images/cassette.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    z-index:50;
}
`
```

You can see on the iPhone that the bottom of the title div falls underneath the cassette image div (I'm using visible borders to show where it's not working properly). What I want is for it to layer on top so I can move it down to look like this: http://lisadearaujo.com/clientaccess/wot-sound/images/screen.jpg

The page is here: http://lisadearaujo.com/clientaccess/wot-sound/indexiPad.html

You can see the rest of the css via the source, obviously...

Any ideas, I would be very, very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Check the z-index on your `div`s that contain `#playlistTitle`